# Getting date with jQuery and saving it to MySQL with a PHP form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, jquery-ui

I need a small example on sending date to mysql db from a php form. Tried lots of examples but I seems I am missing o step.
I have prepared a form for 3 fields, name last name and birth date. When I fill the form and submit date filed gets crazy :) 0000-00-00 00:00:00

I tried to format the date but this time I could not understand how to pass it to mysql. Here is my funny code;

```
<?php include "header.php" ?>
<?php include "conn.php" ?>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#bdate" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $PlayerName = $_POST['PlayerName'];
        $PlayerLname = $_POST['PlayerLname'];
        $PlayerBdate = $_POST['PlayerBdate'];
        $query = "INSERT INTO tblPlayer (
                PlayerName, PlayerLname, PlayerBdate
    ) VALUES (
        '{$PlayerName}', '{$PlayerLname}', '{$PlayerBdate}'
    )";
        if(mysql_query($query,$connection)){
            //Sucess
            header("Location: players_list.php");
        } else{
            echo "<p>something is wrong</p>";
            echo "<p>" . mysql_error() . "</p>";
        }

    }
?>
<form action="add_player.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
   <td>Name: </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="PlayerName" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Lastname:</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="PlayerLastName" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Birthdate:</td>
   <td><input id="bdate" type="text" name="PlayerBdate" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" /></td>
   <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
<?php ob_end_flush() ?>
<?php include ("footer.php") ?>
```

header.php contains

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
```

and conn.php is the standard connection sting file.Footer.php is just closing the connection:)
Also I could not make my code work without the ob_start(); and end functions:S

So can you point out how can I get the date as day/month/year format and save it to mysql that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your date in mysql is in `Y-m-d H:i:s` format.. use php `date()` function to convert the date into required format.

replace

```
$PlayerBdate = $_POST['PlayerBdate'];
```

with

```
 $PlayerBdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($_POST['PlayerBdate']));
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you:) Can I just omit the hours etc? As this is just an birthday input, does my database needs that information?

Comment: yes you can just pass `date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['PlayerBdate']))`..anyways thanks ...glad it helped.. happy coding

Comment: Also, when I change it to  $PlayerBdate = date('d-m-Y H:i:s',strtotime($_POST['PlayerBdate'])); it does not work. Y-m-d is kind strange for me :)

Comment: i guess that is because in your table structure you are saving your date field as `Y-m-d` format which is like `2001-05-10`.. so it doesnot work... if you need the format as `d-m-Y H:i:s` then u need to change the structure of that feild in db table

Answer (score 0):

The smartest thing would just to make sure your datepicker returns it in the correct format,
$( "#bdate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }); will make the datepicker return it in the correct format. It will be missing the time, but mysql will automatically fill that for you.